# Returning a value/string to a JTextField, IndexoutofboundsException

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

Based upon another Headfirst exercise I'm having trouble with populating my GUI with the data of vehicles. I use a Controller class to manage my vehicle Object class. For some reason I'm getting an index out of range exception.

Gui Class

```
public class ShowroomDriver{
    public static Showroom Cars = new Showroom("Cars");
    public static void main(String[] args) {           
        Showroom Cars = new Showroom("Cars");
        Vehicle vechicle1 = new Vehicle("Ford"); 

        Cars.addVehicle(vechicle1);
        GuiInterface gui = new GuiInterface("Car Showroom");
    }

    private static class GuiInterface extends JFrame {
        private JButton saleButton, previousButton, nextButton;
        private static JTextField textField1;
        private JLabel label1;
        private JPanel[] p = new JPanel[5];
        public GuiInterface(String sTitle) {
            super(sTitle);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            previousButton = new JButton("Previous Car");
            nextButton = new JButton("Next Car");
            saleButton = new JButton("Sale");          

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                p[i] = new JPanel();
            }

            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel formPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));


            textField1 = new JTextField(10);            
            label1 = new JLabel("Manufacture");

            p[0].add(label1);
            p[1].add(textField1);


            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                formPanel.add(p[i]);
            }

            contentPane.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(300,300);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            getField();

            this.setVisible(true);
        }

        private void getField(){
            textField1.setText(Cars.currentVehicle().getManufacutre());
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Class

```
public class Showroom{
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehiclesSold = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<Vehicle> theVehicles;
    private String vechicleType;
    private int arrayPosition = 0;

    public Showroom(String type){
        vechicleType = type;
        theVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    }

    public boolean addVehicle(Vehicle newVehicle){
        theVehicles.add(newVehicle);
        return true;
    }

    public Vehicle currentVehicle(){
        return theVehicles.get(arrayPosition);
    }

    public void getVehicles(){
        System.out.println("---Vehicle Type: " + vechicleType +"---");
        for(Vehicle nextVehicle : theVehicles){
            System.out.println(nextVehicle.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Vehicle Class

```
public class Vehicle{
    private String Manufacture
    Vehicle(String Manufacture){ //There are more
        this.Manufacture = Manufacture;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = "Maufacture: " + getManufacutre()
                "\n";
        return s;
    }

    public String getManufacutre() { return this.Manufacture; }
}
```

Comment: sorry, no idea, for better help sooner post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) , demonstraded only isuue with JTextField, short, runnable, complilable

Comment: The error is IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0. Even though i know there are 4 within the array. I've proven it with a getVehicles method as shown above.

Comment: this exception could be interesting for code I wrote, see  and debug on my screen ....

Comment: I've added further code if your interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more code it is not possible to tell where the error comes from. But from this piece of code, the only place an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can com from is

```
return theVehicles.get(arrayPosition);
```

Your problem is, that `arrayPosition` is wrong.
Try debugging your code for finding out what exactly goes wrong, or post more code

Edit:
You seem to have a misunderstanding on what the `static` keyword does.
`static` objects or methods are something, that is only instantiated once during runtime.
For example your declaration of the `Cars` attribute in `class ShowhroomDriver` means, that the class `ShowroomDriver` has a **single** class attribute named `Cars` (and by the way - do not let attributes start with an uppercase character. This is **very** confusing).

What you want though is to pass an instance of `ShowRoom` (your `Cars` attribute) to your class `GuiInterface` (also remove the `static` keyword there) via its constructor, like this:

```
// ...
private Showroom cars;
public GuiInterface(String sTitle, Showroom cars) {
    // ...
    this.cars = cars;
    // ...
}
```

Then, instead of

```
private void getField(){
    textField1.setText(Cars.currentVehicle().getManufacutre());
}
```

you write

```
private void getField(){
    textField1.setText(this.cars.currentVehicle().getManufacutre());
}
```

Also remove **all** `static` keywords except the one at the `main` method.

Comment: The arrayPosition is default set to 0. I know a Vehicle exists at that location. See my new method i added.

Comment: `getField()` is static. That's most likely the problem. Remove it, and it should work

Comment: Sadly there is no change, Just say what code you need and I'll post it as there is quite abit.

Comment: Post all three classes and remove only, what is not relevant to your problem

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I just can't access the cars variable as you said. I also get "non-static variable this cannon be referenced from a static context" & "non-static variable cars cannot be referenced from a static context." `GuiInterface gui = new GuiInterface("Car Showroom", cars);`

Comment: You did delete all of these `static`s, right?  
`public static Showroom Cars = new Showroom("Cars");`  
`private static class GuiInterface extends JFrame {`  
`private static JTextField textField1;`

Comment: I've double checked there is only static main in that class. `private Showroom cars;` I've done everything exactly as you've said.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it out locally. The private class `GuiInterface` needs to be public and in its own java file (GuiInterface.java).
Also you have a missing semicolon and mismatched brackets in the class `Vehicle`.
On my PC it works...see if you can get it working with fixing the issues in `Vehicle` and `GuiInterface`. If you can't get it working, I'll post my classes

Comment: Ah it works fine but it seems to have caused a new issue. I decided to leave my anonymous actionlistener out of the orignial code. But it seems that doing this has somehow broken it. "method addactionlistener in class abstractbutton cannot be applied to given types.     `previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });`

Comment: Strange...adding the listener works just fine for me. Are you maybe importing a wrong ActionEvent? Should be from `java.awt.event`;

Comment: That was very strange just an IDE error i guess. Thank you very much for being so patient I really appreciate your help.